# Dark fantasy book with moonlight magic, one armed warrior, and a witch with spiders

Tags: identification-request

A dark fantasy book I read years ago had a young woman protagonist who was part of a prophecy. Her magic had something to do with moonlight and its different colours affected what her magic did. There was a one armed warrior helping her, amongst others, trying to overthrow a dark lord as he hunted her.

There was a witch working for the dark lord who used spiders and there was a vivid scene where hundreds of spiders ran up inside her (they were her children) so she could safely move them disguised as a pregnant woman.

Comment: Hi. When was "years ago" approximately? Two years ago in 2022? Seventy years ago in 1950?